# SQL Server Service Broker Service Disappearing (Automatically Deleted)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, service-broker

I've implemented a messaging system over SQL Server Service Broker.  It is working great, with the sole exception that every once in a while (maybe once per week per server) my initiator service just vanishes without a trace.  The corresponding queue is still there, but the service is missing.

Obviously this causes problems in my system.  It's a simple matter to recreate the service by hand, but I'm confused as to what might cause this behavior.  I understand that automatic poison message handling causes *queues* to be disabled, but I don't see anything that indicates *services* can be disabled or deleted automatically.

When this happens, I usually have a large backlog of messages in multiple application queues, but nothing extreme.  Total message backlog is around 200,000.

Does anyone know what might be happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have a bug of some sort that issues a DROP SERVICE statement. That is the only way a service gets deleted.

Check the [default trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175513.aspx), the DROP statement gets traced and saved into it so you can track down the application/user/statement that issues the DROP. Check [sys.traces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178579.aspx) to find the location of the default trace then open the .TRC file in Profiler.

Comment: Thanks, Remus.  I do have code that drops and recreates queues and services during our maintenance cycle; I'll focus on figuring out what's going on there.  Thanks for the tip on the default trace flag; I had not known about that before!